# How to make dynamic ExpandedListView or RecyclerView with category/subcategory?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, broadcastreceiver, expandablelistview

Many examples of creating an ExpandedListView show how to make an already filled ExpandedListView instead of an empty one. And in the same examples, already added categories (parents) and in them we add elements (children). But i need to be able to add in this order: first I add a category (parent), then I add an item to that category (child) and it should immediately dynamically appear on the screen, not after the closing the category. Added n-number of elements, closed the category. Then if needed added another, etc.
The problem with all example implementations is that we adding children in a List or something similar, and in the end "closing" list of child-elements and giving HashMap to Adapter.

What did i do: header (parent, category) adds, dynamically appears. Adds body elements, but they doesnt dynamically appears, if i try to expand category this will make app to crash. After category is closed (all childs sets to List), i can expand category and see all the childrens inside. It may be easier to implement this with RecyclerView? I dont know, like simple class with name field (header) and List of elements (childs)?

My app is catching BroadCastReceiver messages, and my app has a status flag, if the status of the app is "setParent", then the message that came, create a "Category" and become its name, then the program goes to the status "setChild" and the following messages are set as elements (children). If the message value is equal to the "Category.value" then the category is will be closed and the application goes back to the "setParent" status.

```
class DocumentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object{
    var barcodeVal = "empty"
}

var appStatus: AppStatus = AppStatus.setCell

var openCategoryCode: String = ""

// ExpListView
val header: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
val body: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = ArrayList()
var listAdapter: MyListAdapter? = null
val productList : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

private val customBroadcastReceiver = CustomBroadcastReceiver()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(com.bcr.app.R.layout.activity_document)
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter("MESSAGE_RECEIVED"))

    val expListView = findViewById<View>(com.bcr.app.id.expandableListView) as ExpandableListView
    expListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListView, header, body))
}

var broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Check incoming message
        checkMessage()
    }
}

fun checkMessage(){
    if(appStatus == AppStatus.setChild && openCategoryCode == barcodeVal) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Category closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        appStatus = AppStatus.setParent
        body.add(productList)
        listAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    else if(appStatus == AppStatus.setChild && openCategoryCode!= barcodeVal) {
        setChild(barcodeVal)
    }
    else if(appStatus == AppStatus.setParent && openCategoryCode!= barcodeVal) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cell saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        openCellCode = barcodeVal
        appStatus = AppStatus.setChild
        setParent(barcodeVal)
    }
}

fun setParent(barCodeVal: String) {
    try {
        header.add(barcodeVal)
        listAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

fun setChild(barCodeVal: String) {
    try {
        productList.add(productName)
        listAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}}
```

Adapter

```
class ExpandableListAdapter(var context : Context, var expandableListView: ExpandableListView, var header : MutableList<String>, var body : MutableList<MutableList<String>>) :
BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): String {
    return header[groupPosition]
}

override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun getGroupView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View? {
    var convertView = convertView
    if(convertView == null){
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_group, null)
    }
    val title = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textGroup)
    title?.text = getGroup(groupPosition)
    title?.setOnClickListener {
        if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
            expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition)
        else
            expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition)
        //Toast.makeText(context, getGroup(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return convertView
}

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
     return body[groupPosition].size
}

override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): String {
    return body[groupPosition][childPosition]
}

override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
    return groupPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    childPosition: Int,
    isLastChild: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View? {
    var convertView = convertView
    if(convertView == null){
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, null)
    }
    val title = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChild)
    title?.text = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)
    title?.setOnClickListener {
        //Toast.makeText(context, getChild(groupPosition, childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return convertView
}

override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
    return childPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return header.size
}}
```